# How do I make a sql sentence to do order by before distinct?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, I have this `order` table, and it has columns: order_id, user_id, create_time, city_id.

Now I want to get the entry of an user's most recent order so basically what I want to do is:

```
select distinct(order.user_id), city_id 
from order 
where city_id != 0 
order by create_time desc
```

But as far as I know `distinct` will run before `order by`, which means there's already only one `user_id` left for each user before it reaches `order by`, so what do I do to make `order by` run first?

Comment: That makes no sense at all. Add sample table data, and the expected result - and describe why you want that result.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what you want to achieve here?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function (on a column), it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and is applied on the whole selected rows. To make this much clearer, simply remove those redundant parentheses and write `select distinct order.user_id, city_id ... ` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have a sub-query that returns each user's most recent create_time. `JOIN` with that result.

```
select o1.user_id, o1.city_id 
from order o1
join (select user_id, max(create_time) as newest_create_time
      from order
      where city_id != 0
      group by user_id) o2
    on o1.user_id = o2.user_id and o1.create_time = o2.newest_create_time
where o1.city_id != 0
```